# Issue with Prompts.choice if the user’s reply is not in the list of options

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, chatbot

If the user enters by text an option that is not in the list, I want it to  exit and fort the buttons not to appear again.

If user enters anything different to "Ver más", then I want to leave the choice option.

```js
 async choiceCardStep(stepContext) {

        const options = {
            prompt: '',
            retryPrompt: '',
            choices: this.getChoices()
        };
}

 getChoices() {
 
        const cardOptions = [{
                value: 'Ver más',
                synonyms: ['Ver más']

            },
        ];

        return cardOptions;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of channel you are using ? If you are using web chat then disable the previous button once you enter the text in chat window using any front-end framework.

Comment: If I am using web chat and direct line speech, I only want that if the user enters something other than "See more" by text that the button does not appear again, how could I do that?

Comment: When you are designing any kind of card there will be a 'id' using that you can add front-end script to disable ( id will be part of that particular button ). While user enter text in chat without selecting the button then you can pickup the id ( If the content is fixed of that button then use the value of the text and button id for disable purpose - I never prefer text better to use individual button id ).